# Parametrized HQL update query troubles

Tags: hibernate, hql, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to update entity's property, but I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

The method's body contains problems:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("UPDATE Author SET expiredDate = :date where id = :id")
            .setParameter("date", new Date())
            .setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
```

The Author entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "AUTHORS_SEQ", sequenceName = "AUTHORS_SEQ")
public class Author implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "author_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AUTHORS_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "author_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "expired")
    private Date expiredDate;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "NEWS_AUTHORS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "NEWS_ID")})
    private Set<News> newsSet;
//... getters and setters ...
```

What does wrong in my query?

Comment: Can you show us the `Author` class?

Comment: Is this exactly the way you create and run the query? Is the query maybe a named query which you posted here in-place just for brevity, or something like that?

Comment: It is the body of a DAO layer method. Also all DAO classes are Transactional. I never use a NamedQuery annotation.@DraganBozanovic

Comment: Only for test, try to put the annotation `@Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` in expiredDate column.

Comment: @Dherik It doesn't help)

Comment: Does this error occur with any `update`?